# Image upload in non existing folder in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I've run into a problem where I need to upload an image into a folder and store its path into database.

If the folder is not present then create the new folder and then store it there and save full path into database.

```
    $file_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"];
    $temp_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["tmp_name"];
    $imgtype=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["type"];
    $ext= GetImageExtension($imgtype);
```

*image name to be used*

```
    $imagename=("Userimage")."-".time().$ext;
```

*image path*

```
$target_path = "images/".$imagename
```

Condition

```
if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target_path))
{
    $query_upload="INSERT into images_tbl (images_path , submission_date) VALUES ('".$target_path."','".date("Y-m-d")."')";
    $imagedb= mysqli_query($con,$query_upload);

while($imagepath = mysqli_fetch_array($imagedb))
    {
        echo "success";
    }  
}
```

Comment: and where's the problem?

Comment: you might want to add something like this: `if(!is_dir($target_path)) { mkdir($target_path, 0755, true); }`  - but make sure to only use the path here, not the target-filename!

Answer (score 1):

It's easy:

```
 $target_path = 'images/'.$imagename;
 if(!is_dir($target_path)) mkdir($target_path, 0755);
```

Don't use " " when you can use ' ', because each time you use " .." , php try to find variable inside and lost time for nothing. ;)

Comment: but i need that new folder inside the images folder every time i run the code and its requirement is to check that the folder exists or not

Comment: the new folder can be the name of a user fetched from a column of a database table  and the folder will be created inside the images folder named as of that user  only

Comment: You can make th folder where you want with mkdir. My example check if not exist... and make it if it's false.

Comment: Of course, you can adapt the name and direction of the folder like you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
<?php
$target_dir = preg_replace('#^(.*)'.basename($target_path).'$#', '$1', $target_path);
if (!is_dir($target_dir))
    mkdir($target_dir, 0755);

if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target_path))
{
    $query_upload="INSERT into images_tbl (images_path , submission_date) VALUES ('".$target_path."','".date("Y-m-d")."')";
    $imagedb= mysqli_query($con,$query_upload);

while($imagepath = mysqli_fetch_array($imagedb))
    {
        echo "success";
    }  
}
?>
```

The preg_replace part strips the directory path out of the complete path.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!file_exists('path/to/directory')) {
    mkdir('path/to/directory', 0777, true);
}
```

0777 is the directory permission ,that is a creating the directory and setting the permission to 0777 so that file can be uploaded to this directory